# Array Loop in a Loop need two time foreach?

Tags: php, arrays

## I want the picture captions to be looped too. What am I doing wrong?

**images in dir array**

```php
$imgsArray = array(
'first Image big', 'first Image small',
'second Image big', 'second Image small',
'third Image big', 'third Image small',
);
```

**picture caption array**

```php
//img caption//////////////
$imgCaption = array(
'caption 1',
'caption 2',
'caption 3'
);
```

**what i tried:**

```php
/// Picture data
        foreach($imgsArray as $files => $img){
          $first_char = substr($img,0,strpos($img,"-"));
          if ($first_char != $last_entry) {
// If there are more pictures than captions in array, leave the last caption blank            
if(!isset($imgCaption[$files])){$imgCaption[$files] = '';}
   echo'<figure>
         <img  src="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'img/'.$first_char.'-small.jpg" alt="'.$imgCaption[$files].'" 
srcset="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'img/'.$first_char.'-big.jpg 734w,'
         .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'img/'.$first_char.'-small.jpg 1472w,'
>';
      echo '<figcaption>'.$imgCaption[$files].'</figcaption>';
   echo '</figure>';
          }
          $last_entry = $first_char;
        };
```

> I tried to simplify the result:

**unexpected**

- First Image: caption 1
- Second Image:
- Third Image:

**expected**

- First Image: caption 1
- Second Image: caption 2
- Third Image: caption 3

Comment: `// If there are more pictures than titles, leave the last titles blank            
    if(!isset($imgCaption[$files])){$imgCaption[$files] = '';}` 
what are you trying to do here ?

Comment: for example there are 12 pictures in the picture array, but only 4 in caption array, then leave the remaining pictures caption empty

Comment: Could you give a sample (simplified, probably) of what is in imgsArray?

Comment: $imgsArray = array(
'first Image',
'second Image',
'third Image'
);

Comment: @CemFirat I don't think this if statement is working as you want it to work.

Comment: `if(!isset($imgCaption[$files])){$imgCaption[$files] = '';}`
comment this if statement and try.

Comment: if i comment this line, than i get this message: Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in /var/www/dist/lib/layBlogArticle.php on line 158,
also only the first caption is showing

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in a slightly different approach. I would combine images and captions array and then loop through that merged array:

```
<?php
$imgsArray = array(
    'first Image',
    'second Image',
    'third Image'
);

$imgCaption = array(
    'caption 1 for first Image',
    null, //Just for the example
    'caption 3 for third Image'
);

//Merge images and captions into one array
$imagesCaptions = array();
foreach($imgsArray as $key=>$image) {
    $caption = '';
    if (!empty($imgCaption[$key])) {
        $caption = $imgCaption[$key];
    }
    $imagesCaptions[] = array('image'=>$image, 'caption'=>$caption); 
}
```

The result of the array would be:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'image' => string 'first Image' (length=11)
      'caption' => string 'caption 1 for first Image' (length=25)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'image' => string 'second Image' (length=12)
      'caption' => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'image' => string 'third Image' (length=11)
      'caption' => string 'caption 3 for third Image' (length=25)
```

Easier to use this loop:

```
/// Now... you loop through $imageCaptions array and create whatever you want.
foreach($imagesCaptions as $item) {
    $image = $item['image'];
    $caption = $item['caption'];
    //Use $image and $caption to create your string (figure)...
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have corrected the question. Image array (different image sizes) doesn't work with them